# Getting the index of a list for the first value that satisfies a criterion

Tags: python

I have a list

```
a = [1.0, 1.2, 1.1, 1.4, 0.1]
```

and from that list I would like to get the *index* of the *first* value that satisfies some criterion, say `x > 1.1`

What would be a good way of doing this in python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine `next` and `enumerate`:

```
>>> next(i for i,x in enumerate(a) if x > 1.1)
1
>>> next(i for i,x in enumerate(a) if x > 1.3)
3
```

or

```
>>> next((i,x) for i,x in enumerate(a) if x > 1.3)
(3, 1.4)
```

if you wanted both.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
def analyze(l, criteria):
    for idx in range(len(l)):
        if criteria(l[idx]):
            return idx
```

And then use it like this:

```
a = [1.0, 1.2, 1.1, 1.4, 0.1]
analyze(a, lambda x: x > 1.1)
```

I don't think it too pythonic. There are probably more pythonic ways.

Comment: This returns the value, not the index.

Comment: @will: Oh! I see. Will change it then.

Comment: I also agree that it's not very pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is perhaps a *little* more pythonic than some of the other answers - if that's what you're after.

```
a = [1.0, 1.2, 1.1, 1.4, 0.1]

def crit(x):
    return x > 1.3

index = None
for i,v in enumerate(a):
    if crit(v):
        index = i
        break

print index
```